# What's the meaning of the spell's name that Wendy uses to cure Natsu's vehicle-sickness?

Tags: fairy-tail

In chapter 152 Wendy cures Natsu's sickness for vehicles. When doing this enchantment/spell she says `TROIA`:

[image: Spell Casting]

What does that mean? Is it just a random word?

I ask this because `troia` is the Italian word for `whore`, but I hope it isn't related to this.  I'm reading the manga in English, so that's not an Italian translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably just a random word created by the mangaka for the spell's name. It's probably just a coincidence that Troia meant whore in Italian translation. After all, it's a healing magic so it won't make sense that the mangaka chose that kind of word intentionally if knew that meaning in Italian translation. You can find Troia's full description [here](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Troia).